# Laravel Model recursion supress infinite loop

Tags: php, recursion, laravel-5, error-handling, eloquent

Having the following Laravel recursion in my model how do I avoid accidentally registered relation. What I mean: I have users and users can have many reportees and we want to get back the tree on a given user with the following snippet, which is works fine till the point if user is not a reportee to itself

```php
/**
 * User can have many Reporters
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function hasreporters()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'reporting_to', 'acc_receiving_from_id', 'acc_reporting_to_id')
        ->where('status', 'A');
}

/**
 * @return $this
 */
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasreporters()->with(['children']);
}
```

where can I check in the loop if a given id is not equal to the parent id

Answer (score 0):

In function `children()` you are use relation as query builder. It`s not wrong way, but method`->with()` search relation from its argument, then call it. Here is recursion :) Try:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasreporters();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but with this refactoring I would still have the problem of accidentally registered relation issue and the script would enter in an infinite loop and after all I would end up in memory overflow